# Categorising overall probabilities of jobs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

**EDIT**

So I've managed to get everything largely working using the SUMIF function as follows.

**For <30% and >70%:**

```
=SUMIF(D2:D392,"<30%",E2:E392)
```

**For 30-70%:**

```
=SUMIF(D2:D392,">=30%",E2:E392)-SUMIF(D2:$D392,">70%",E2:E392)
```

However, is the second function (for 30-70%) the most ideal way to get the total number of jobs between 30-70% chance of computerisation? Or is there a cleaner function I could use instead?

**/EDIT**

I have a list of occupations with a probability of computerisation in one column, and a total number of jobs within each occupation.

[image: Link]

I want to get the total number of jobs and the percentage of total jobs into three categories: those with less than 30% probability of computerisation, those with a 30-70% probability, and those with a greater than 70% chance.

[image: Link]

I am unsure what function allows me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework and you should show some effort to solve it yourself.

What you need is an [IF statement](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/11/26/if-function-excel/)

```
=IF(B2<30%;C2;0) + IF(B3<30%;C3;0)
```

This does the following:
`IF` cell B2 contains a value lesser then `<` 30% this cell equals the value of C2, if not, it sets it to zero. It then adds `+` the result of the next criteria (C3 or 0).
Keep adding your other 3.

Then google how to use the AND command to get the in-between stuff and use what you now have learned to do the greater than and the percentage cells.

Note: depending on localization of your Excel version, you might need to swap the semicolons to commas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've discovered that SUMIF does the same thing but for the entire column, which is great. However, I can't work out if (or how) to use the AND function with SUMIF to get cells with a probability between 30-70%. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to show some effort yourself, edit your question to include what you have tried and you might get help to go in the right direction. The point isn't for you to solve this specific problem.
If you learn how these basic statements work, you will be able to solve ALL similar problems (and several others) in the future.